# How to Right Align Print a Python Integer List

Tags: python-3.x

I have three lists like:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]
l3 = [7, 8, 9]
```

I want to print these in following manner:

```
Fruits          Quantity
Mango           1, 2, 3
Banana          4, 5, 6
Strawberry      7, 8, 9
```

How can I do the right alignment of the numbers in the list in python 3?
It seems an easy task. I have read many formatting tutorials online and looked in stack overflow   answers but couldn't find one which can be used in my case. Maybe because I'm a total beginner in python so couldn't understand how to apply those in my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `zip()` along with [`ljust()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/ljust.html) that *Returns the string left justified in a string of specified length*:

```
headers = ["Fruits", "Quantity"]
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]
l3 = [7, 8, 9]
l4 = ["Mango", "Banana", "Strawberry"]


print(''.ljust(15).join(head for head in headers))

for fruit, quantity in zip(l4, [l1,l2,l3]):
    print(fruit.ljust(20), ', '.join([str(quan) for quan in quantity]))
```

OUTPUT:

```
Fruits               Quantity                                                                                                                                                
Mango                1, 2, 3                                                                                                                                                 
Banana               4, 5, 6                                                                                                                                                 
Strawberry           7, 8, 9
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to align quantity list, you can align their descriptive names (i.e fruits):

```
fruits = {"Mango": [1, 2, 3],
          "Banana": [4, 5, 6],
          "Strawberry": [7, 8, 9]}

for fruit, quantity in fruits.items():
    print(f"{fruit:15}", ", ".join(str(i) for i in quantity))
```

```
Mango           1, 2, 3
Banana          4, 5, 6
Strawberry      7, 8, 9
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to work with your l1-l3 lists:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]
l3 = [7, 8, 9]
l4 = ["Mango", "Banana", "Strawberry"]
    
print(f"{'Fruits':15}Quantity")
[print(f"{key:15}{', '.join([str(num) for num in value])}") for key, value in dict(zip(l4, [l1,l2,l3])).items()]
```

OUTPUT:

```
Fruits         Quantity
Mango          1, 2, 3
Banana         4, 5, 6
Strawberry     7, 8, 9
```